# Override Automapper to map two objects which all properties have similar name

Tags: c#, overriding, automapper

I have a lot of objects that have all the same properties with similar names, like this:

```
class 1 {
     public string Id 
     public string Name 
     public string Value 
}

class 2 {
     public string Idk__BackingFieldField;
     public string Namek__BackingFieldField;
     public string Valuek__BackingFieldField;
}
```

And I'm trying to achieve that the automapper maps all the objects with a method that considers that the only difference between the properties is the "__BackingFieldField" string at the end.
So far I couldn't do it.
It is possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg=>
    {
        cfg.RecognizeDestinationPostfixes("k__BackingFieldField");  
    });
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    Mapper.Map<ItemDto>(new Item { Name = "Name" }).Dump();
}
public class Item
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class ItemDto
{
    public string Namek__BackingFieldField{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a great help. I'm new with automapper and the possible solutions we were thinking were a lot more complex than this.